# In extract-text-plugin options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

In a express Js project  i am install extract-text-plugin service. Using this webpack service i want minimize the js and css code. When i use minimize into option I gives a error.Error is :  options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }. 
Webpack run perfectly when we do not use minimize property in option.

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
entry: './config.js',
output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + './public/javascripts'),
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                ]
            })
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("../stylesheets/app.css"),
]
}
```